# Dual-boot OS selection

Tags: system-installation

After dual-boot with Windows 8 and Ubuntu, at startup no option for OS selection is coming. Windows starts without any option. How do I get OS selection option ?

Comment: How did you install the two OS? Give some more details.

Comment: Windows 8 was pre-installed on my system. Then i installed Ubuntu using bootable pendrive on separate partition of 80GB and 2GB of swap area on harddisk. On restarting Windows 8 boots directly. Even after starting windows no volume of 80GB is showing up.

Comment: Please edit your question to include all the installation information.

Comment: Nothing wrong here. Load your Ubuntu Live CD and install boot-repair, run it, wait a little bit until it is done running, then reboot.

Answer (score 3):

How to get back the OS Selectoin option:

Make a bootable Pen drive of Ubuntu(12.04 or 14.04). Start your laptop with Bootable Ubuntu Pen-drive and select

- Try Ubuntu without installing

Open up the terminal and Install BootRepairDisk from the link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

After Installing it Launch the BootRepair software. It will look like following image

[image]

And Select **Recommended repair option**. Make sure you have a Internet connection because it will download some of the grub related packages. And wait for some time till the process completes.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

How many disks does your computer have?, Have you installed ubuntu after windows?, during ubuntu installation have you chosen the default values for everything?,if so and if you only have one hdd/sdd, the ubuntu installer, should have installed grub in the right place, and everything should work. If you installed ubuntu in a separate partition, you must select in the BIOS the disk in which grub (ubuntu) is installed to boot first.
If you installed windows over ubuntu, the windows installer probably has overwritten grub and thats why you are not getting anything.

Comment: I have only one HDD. I installed Ubuntu after windows and on separate partition. Now what did I do for OS selection menu ?

Answer (score 0):

install grub and reboot your pc. After reboot it will show both ubuntu and windows.

Comment: Can you include in your answer the instructions on how to do that?

Comment: sudo apt-get install grub,then reboot